# Angularstrap popover data-template making GET requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I'm trying to convert an Express app templated with EJS to Angular. When trying to use the Angular Strap popover I want the popover content to show the data from a HTML partial. The problem is when I reference the file the server makes a GET request for that route and cannot be found.

My express configuration has the `index.html` file in a `templates` folder. The statics are in a `public` folder in a neighboring directory. The complete folder structure looks like this:

```
app
--public
--templates
  -index.html
  -user.html
```

The popover content I want is in user.html and it's being referenced from index.html. My angular code looks like this:

```
<a
  title="User Info"
  data-content="test"
  data-template="/user.html"
  bs-popover>whatever</a>
```

I've tried `user.html`, `/user.html`, and any combination of those. In the console it throws a 404 error from the root saying that http://hostname.com/user.html doesn't exist. My question is, how do I reference a partial html file in angular and get it to point to the right file and not to a GET request to the server?

I've also tried using angular-ui-bootstrap but it lacks partials support.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files need to be in the folder defined by your Express configuration as the statics folder. So `/user.html` is looking in `public/user.html` for the file. If it doesn't find it, then it sends a GET request to the server.